# Domino 9.x calendar service create meeting

Tags: rest, calendar, lotus-domino

I have been following this guide to work on Domino 9.0.1

[Domino Calendar services](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Calendar_events_POST&content=apicontent)

I am using JSON and the POST command works but creates an appointment, what I want to do is create a meeting. I have tried setting other fields like event['x-lotus-appttype'].data or event.AppointmentType = 3 but I still get an appointment.

JSON I am sending

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "summary":"Meeting 1",
      "location":"Location 1",
      "start": {
        "date":"2013-12-01",
        "time":"13:00:00",
        "utc":true
      },
      "end": {
        "date":"2013-12-01",
        "time":"14:00:00",
        "utc":true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the correct JSON format to create a meeting ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following documentation: [Event with attendees represented in JSON format](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=JSON_representation_of_an_event_das901&content=apicontent)

> EXAMPLE 4.  Event with attendees and time zone array:

```
{
  "x-lotus-charset": {
    "data": "UTF-8"
  },
  "timezones": [
    {
      "tzid": "Eastern",
      "standard": {
        "start": {
          "date": "1950-11-05",
          "time": "02:00:00"
        },
        "offsetFrom": "-0400",
        "offsetTo": "-0500",
        "recurrenceRule": "FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=0"
      },
      "daylight": {
        "start": {
          "date": "1950-03-12",
          "time": "02:00:00"
        },
        "offsetFrom": "-0500",
        "offsetTo": "-0400",
        "recurrenceRule": "FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=0"
      }
    }
  ],
  "events": [
    {
      "href": "/mail/dlawson.nsf/api/calendar/events/DB7E0BAC21EC322A85257BD200756E26-Lotus_Notes_Generated",
      "id": "DB7E0BAC21EC322A85257BD200756E26-Lotus_Notes_Generated",
      "summary": "Staff meeting",
      "location": "Ray's office",
      "description": "Please email your status update 24 hours before the meeting.",
      "start": {
        "date": "2013-09-12",
        "time": "09:00:00",
        "tzid": "Eastern"
      },
      "end": {
        "date": "2013-09-12",
        "time": "10:00:00",
        "tzid": "Eastern"
      },
      "class": "public",
      "transparency": "opaque",
      "sequence": 0,
      "last-modified": "20130825T212457Z",
      "attendees": [
        {
          "role": "chair",
          "status": "accepted",
          "rsvp": false,
          "displayName": "Duke Lawson/Peaks",
          "email": "DukeLawson@swg.usma.ibm.com"
        },
        {
          "role": "req-participant",
          "status": "needs-action",
          "rsvp": true,
          "displayName": "Dean Melnyk/Peaks",
          "email": "DeanMelnyk@swg.usma.ibm.com"
        },
        {
          "role": "req-participant",
          "status": "needs-action",
          "rsvp": true,
          "displayName": "Raymond Chan/Peaks",
          "email": "RaymondChan@swg.usma.ibm.com"
        }
      ],
      "organizer": {
        "displayName": "Duke Lawson/Peaks",
        "email": "DukeLawson@swg.usma.ibm.com"
      },
      "x-lotus-broadcast": {
        "data": "FALSE"
      },
      "x-lotus-notesversion": {
        "data": "2"
      },
      "x-lotus-appttype": {
        "data": "3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I hope this can help :)

Comment: UTC? Where can I get the info for UTC?